Npm run build doesnt build all the css
Im using Laravel, Vite, Tailwind CSS and all worked last week. Today, a reboot brought it to its knees. Npm run build wont build the things well, the site is a bit fallen apart. Most of the CSS things work, but some others dont (like paddings-margins).
Im new to it, how to investigate?
My vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});


Sometimes if you define tailwind classes like
`px-${variable_number}`

The classes are not found and get purged, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

sadly the case is not that simple here

That's a shame. Perhaps a node_modules issue. If you delete the node_modules folder and then npm install and try again, does it have the same issue?

sorry Im an idiot and wasnt trying from the right directory
